# Não consigo manipular dados que vem do Web Service (Json)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

Eu estou tentando pegar o resultado de uma requisição para uma API (json), e envia-la para uma outra função que irá gravar no localstorage, eu até consegui com o valor do produto, mas com o nome que é string não está funcionando, já tentei dar trim(), substr() e nada altera o valor da variavel onde está o retorno do dado do json.

Codigo abaixo:

```
function openModalquantidade(key){

    $.getJSON("http://www.outletclube.com/web_api/products/", function(data) {

        $('.modal').modal('show');

        var imgWS = data.Products[key].Product.ProductImage[0].http;
        var nomeWS = data.Products[key].Product.name;
        nomeWS.toString(); 
        nomeWS.substr(1, 5); 
        console.log(nomeWS);
        var precoWS = data.Products[key].Product.promotional_price;
        console.log(precoWS);
        //var quantidadeWS = document.getElementById("quantidade").value;


        var output2='<div class="add-product">';
           output2+='<img src="' + imgWS + '" />'; 
           output2+='<p class="nome">' + nomeWS + '</p>';
           output2+='<p class="preco-antigo">' + precoWS + '</p>';
           output2+='<p><input type= "text" id="quantidade" name="quantidade" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Digite a quantidade"></p>';
           output2+='<p><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="saveListWS(' + nomeWS +')">Comprar</button></p>';
        output2+='</div>';

        document.getElementById("modal-body").innerHTML = output2;

        //$('.modal-body').html(output2);

    });
}
```

Comment: Qual é o output de `console.log(nomeWS);`?

Comment: `key` se esta usando while/for/each ? e por que não tenta inspecionar o seu console para consultar é facilidade.

Comment: Tiago coloque aí o codigo relativo à inserção no localstorage, e o que corre mal quando esta acontece sff

Comment: Eu vou subir uma versão para o git, ou para o js fiddle para vocês conferirem